# How to merge DataRow()

Tags: vb.net

I have a DataTable (dt) which I need to filter under certain conditions I can only use 'Select'. I wrote code that work, but I want do it better:

```
        Dim result As DataTable = dt.Clone
        Dim r1 As DataRow() = Nothing
        Dim r2 As DataRow() = Nothing
        Dim r3 As DataRow() = Nothing
        If dt IsNot Nothing AndAlso dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            r1 = dt.Select("A < " & Quote(Date.UtcNow) & " AND B IS NULL")
            r2 = dt.Select("B > " & Quote(Date.UtcNow) & " AND A IS NULL")
            r3 = dt.Select("A < " & Quote(Date.UtcNow) & " AND B > " & Quote(Date.UtcNow))
        End If

        For i As Integer = 0 To r1.Length -1
            result.ImportRow(r1(i))
        Next
        For i As Integer = 0 To r2.Length -1
            result.ImportRow(r2(i))
        Next
        For i As Integer = 0 To r3.Length -1
            result.ImportRow(r3(i))
        Next
```

I cant find any solution to save result dt.Select to one DataRow() object and then do just one For loop. I am asking for suggestions,
Thanks!

Comment: Why are you doing three separate `Select` calls in the first place? Have you not heard of the `OR` operator? That's exactly what your code results in, i.e. rows that match the first condition or the second condition or the third condition, so why not just put all that into a single Boolean expression?

Comment: you're right, I've made it difficult for myself

Answer (score 0):

In the morning I woke up with a fresh head and something that should have been obvious was a terrible time for me yesterday - `OR` - it settled the matter + `CopyToDataTable()`

```
    If dt IsNot Nothing AndAlso dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        dt = dt.Select("(A < " & Quote(Date.UtcNow) & " AND B IS NULL) OR (B > " & Quote(Date.UtcNow) & " AND A IS NULL) OR (A < " & Quote(Date.UtcNow) & " AND B  > " & Quote(Date.UtcNow) & ")").CopyToDataTable()
    End If

    Return dt
```

Thank you for your time and especially ***jmcilhinney***